# Powershell: GUI input to text file

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I've created an input box with PowerShell. When I want to save the input to a text file I get this in the text file:

```
path=System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: MYINPUTTEDTEXT.text\
```

Code to output the text:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'ascii'
$textinput="$textfieldfolder.text"
write-output "path=$textinput\" >> User-Generated\preferences.ini
```

But I would like to have only:

```
path=MYINPUTTEDTEXT\
```

Thanks for your help!

JJB

Comment: Assuming `$textfieldfolder` is a reference to the input textbox, then `$textinput=$textfieldfolder.text` (without quotes). Otherwise, show the code of your input gui

Comment: @jjb try $exportyouwant |out-file -filepath c:\temp\filename.ini -encoding ascii

Comment: @KemalK. I get the same result.

Comment: @Theo $textfieldfolder is the reference. And thanks! It works!